# Why is this div jumping across the screen when I change the transform origin to right?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

I have some divs that create a book link that opens up when hovered over, I'm trying to make my the book look more 3d by adding another red div with the class of .book-side to the left of the book and rotating it 90 degrees with a transform, with some perspective to make it look more boxy. I did this and noticed the edges of .bookside were going past the height of the book slightly. I figured this was because I set transform-origin was left, so it was rotating on its y axis towards book and not away form it. When I try to fix this by changing the transform-origin to right, .book-side jumps half way across the screen, I have also notices if I rotate it and set top to 0, it ends up in the middle of the top edge of its parent .front-of-book-front. I'm also having to use negative numbers to get it aligned with the top egde of its parent, something that normally you can do by simply setting top to 0, why do I have this odd behavior and how can I fix it?

html is in the jsfiddle, if you look closely towards the bottom of the of the book spine you can see the .book-side goes past the book a bit.
https://jsfiddle.net/ouwrhpwy/2/

```
    .front-of-book-front,
    .back-of-book-front,
    .book-front,
    .book-back,
    .book{
        width: 100px;
        height: 160px;
        position: relative;
        perspective: 1000px;
    }
    .book{
         margin: 52px auto;
         transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
        }
    .book-front{
            position: relative;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-origin: left;
            transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);     
             }
    .front-of-book-front{
            background-image: url("images/mainCover.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: 47%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            perspective: 300px;
            perspective-origin: -150px;
            }
    .front-of-book-front:before{
        content: "Seraph Chronicles: Evangelion";
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        font-size: .5em;
        line-height: 15px;
        color: white;
        width: 119px;
        height: 15px;
        background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.5);
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translate(8px,93px) rotate(90deg);
    }
    .front-of-book-front:after{
        content: "";
        width: 75px;
        height: 12px;
        background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.5);
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(0px,19px);
      }
     .bar{
        width: 80px;
        height: 8px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        font-size: .3em;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
        transform: rotate(90deg) translate(36px,-45px);
         }

    .bar p{
        padding: 2px 3px 0 0 ;
        display: block;
    }
    .back-of-book-front{
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        background-color: rgb(240,234,214);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .book-front:hover{
        transform: rotatey(-180deg);
            }
    .book:hover{
        transform: rotate(10deg);
                }

    .book-back{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        background-color: rgb(240,234,214);
        z-index: -1;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .book-side{
        width: 160px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: red;hsl(1,0%,45%);
        position: absolute;
        left: -2px;//why the negative numbers?
        top:-5px;//why cant I simply just set it to 0?
        transform: rotate(90deg) rotateX(90deg);
        transform-origin: left;//when set to right it jump half way across the srceen
        font-size: .5em;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .book-side p{
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .book-back p{
        font-size: .1em;
        margin: 2.5em 1.5em;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

By tweaking the size and positioning a bit, you can get the .book-side to fit properly.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouwrhpwy/3/) of your book, with the following adjustments to .book-side:

`width: 158px;
height: 8px;
top: -3px`